# How can I pad a file beyond 1024 characters in a unix environment?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sh, sunos

I have a file that I need to pad each line with spaces to around 1100 characters from a `bash` script. Each line in the file currently has 900 characters.

The natural way to to this is

```
awk -F, '{printf("%-1100s\n",$0)}'  src.txt > dst.txt
```

However, I get an error telling me

```
awk: formatted string too long
 record number 1
```

After some experimentation and searching on the internet, I've determined that the maximum line length of formatted string `awk` can handle is 1024.

Is there a better way to get around this limitation?

(note: I'm runnin on SunOS 5.10, and I can't add GNU tools to it, etc.)

Comment: I can't reproduce it even when using BSD awk

Comment: Try `while read line; do printf "%1100s\n" $line; done < src.txt > dst.txt`

Comment: n.b., changed to left justify and pad on the right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get GNU awk.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%-1100s\n", "foo"}'
     foo
```

You're probably using old, broken `awk` - use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` on Solaris. If you're having this problem with one of them, then use the other one.

Comment: I see you added a note that says "I'm runnin on SunOS 5.10". Why did you tag your question linux then??? You're probably using old, broken awk - use nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk on Solaris.

Comment: Linux->SunOS - Corrected, my bad.

Comment: `nawk` was the answer : nawk -F, '{printf("%1100s\n",$0)}'  src.txt > dst.txt

Answer (score 2):

There was one other solution I came up with:

```
awk -F, '{printf("%-900s\n",$0)}'  src.txt > tmp1.txt
awk -F, '{printf("%200s\n","")}'  src.txt > tmp2.txt
paste -d "\0" tmp1.txt tmp2.txt > dst.txt
```

This results in the same file as

```
nawk -F, '{printf("%-1100s\n",$0)}' src.txt > dst.txt
```

Comment: More like desperation - 10 Q

Answer (score 1):

If you have `perl` installed on that system (probably yes), you can set a script like this, and then run it like `pad.pl input.txt 1100 > output.txt`.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

open (INPUT, "<$ARGV[0]");
$LENGTH=$ARGV[1];

while (<INPUT>) {
    chomp($_);
    while (length($_) < $LENGTH ) { $_ = $_." "; }
    print $_."\n";
}

close INPUT;
```

Comment: Why not just take the length `$l` of the line and add `($LENGTH - $l) x " "` to it?

Comment: Yes, I think you can do that - it should be faster, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
awk '{ pad=1100-length($0); x = $0; 
    while (pad > 0) { x = x " "; pad--}; print x }' src.txt >dst.txt
```

... which avoids use of `printf()` completely but does multiple string concatenations instead.